# JavaMail and IMAP. How to avoid confirmation messages?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, imap

I'm developing an IMAP client with JavaMail 1.4 (the server is MS Exchange 2010). I noticed that confirmation messages (read/not read) are sent to Outlook clients that ask for them. Is there a way to disable this feature?

Answer (score 0):

Normally delivery status notifications (delivered, not delivered) are sent by the server and message status notifications (read, not read) are sent by the client.  I'm not familiar with how Exchange handles this but it sounds like the message status notifications are being sent by the server.  Perhaps this only works for clients using the proprietary Microsoft protocol instead of IMAP.  I have no idea if there's a way to disable this using the IMAP protocol; if there is it would be a proprietary extension.

Note that you can set the "peek" flag in IMAPMessage, which will prevent the server from marking the message "read".  That may help in this case.